# Replacing a string in an array, where the part of the string is an int

Tags: java, arrays, string, replace, substring

I have code where I have a constructor for an object with mixed data types:

```
public GuidedTour(String tourID, String tourDescription, double tourFee,
        String tourDate, int tourSize, String tourLeader)
```

I need to be able to allow the user to update the `tourSize`.

I can search and find particular tours, but am having trouble working out how to replace a substring with an inputted int value `int newTourSize`.

So the code I am trying to make the replacement is:

```
String tourDetails;
String newDetails = tourDetails.replace(tourSize, newTourSize);
```

It won't let me do it, as I am using int values. I have trying parsing the int into a String.

I am stuck on how to do this, beyond putting all the values back in, the original values with the new value, I am sure it would be better to find and replace that part of the substring and write this new string into the array.

I'm floundering a bit *(but have improved much since my first java questions here!)*

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like your class looks like this:

```
public class GuidedTour {
    private String tourDetails;

    public GuidedTour(String tourID, int tourSize) { // other arguments omitted for brevity
        this.tourDetails = tourID + tourSize;
    }

    public String getTourDetails() {
        return tourDetails;
    }
}
```

And that you're now wondering how to change the `tourSize` into the `tourDetails`.

Well, it's easy. Don't forget about the parts of the tour details. Replace your class by something like

```
public class GuidedTour {
    private String tourID;
    private int tourSize;

    public GuidedTour(String tourID, int tourSize) { // other arguments omitted for brevity
        this.tourID = tourID;
        this.tourSize = tourSize;
    }

    public String getTourDetails() {
        return tourID + tourSize;
    }

    public void setTourSize(int newTourSize) {
        this.tourSize = newTourSize;
    }
}
```

Now you don't need to do any String replacement anymore. You just set the new tour size, and ask the `GuidedTour` instance to recreate the `tourDetails` String by reassembling all the parts.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to convert a primitive typed value to a `String`, do that:

```
String.valueOf(tourSize)
```

The `String` class contains several static methods for creating a `String` object from various inputs.

Answer (score 2):

An addition of empty string `""` using String Concatenation Operator `"+"`  to any primitive type will result in a string. It is a equivalent operation to `String.valueOf(data)`. For example:

```
String strSize = tourSize+"";
```

Comment: Don't do this!  Suppose your `tourSize` was 7 and your `newTourSize` is 10.  Your `tourDescription` happens to be "Explore the 7 wonders of the world".  Guess what's going to happen!

Comment: @DavidWallace, thank you for pointing out. I have removed the operation from answer. I assumed that op is careful about multiple appearance of same integer in his data string